# Xcode shows swift compiler errors when importing cocoapods generated by gradle plugin

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to use shared code in my iOS project from cocoapods that i created with cocoapods gradle plugin.
Podspec is created without problems.
My shared build.gradle:

```
plugins {
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
id("com.android.library")
id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods")

}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion '30.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
ios()
android()

cocoapods {
    // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
    summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
    homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"

    // The name of the produced framework can be changed.
    // The name of the Gradle project is used here by default.
    frameworkName = "toshlShared"
}

sourceSets {
commonMain.dependencies {
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
}

androidMain.dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
}

iosMain.dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
}
}

}
```

When i run pod install all looks good, but when i run ios app i see this error:

[image]

EDIT: Added my project folder structure with my single .kt file (it is accessible from android code)
[image]

Comment: Hello, can you please tell me if you got .kt source files in your project? This seems like a default header, not the one generated from some Kotlin code.

Comment: I have just one .kt file in my shared code module. It can be called from my android app. Edited my question with project file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem here is caused by the project structure. In the Gradle script, there are three targets declared: an Android one, and `iosX64`+`iosArm64` shortcut(see details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#target-shortcuts)) providing the other two. For this layout, there would be two compilations per iOS target(`iosX64Main, iosX64Test, iosArm64Main, iosArm64Test`) and

> a compilation per Android build variant, for Android targets;

according to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#default-project-layout).
In this particular case, only source file `SharedUtils.kt` is being located in a directory located on an Android `main` compilation's source set. This means it does not get into any iOS compilation. 
To make this source file shared, it should be relocated to the common code. There are two default source sets for common code in Kotlin Multiplatform: `commonMain` and `commonTest`. Therefore, source code should be placed under `src/<sourceSetName>/kotlin` directory(`commonMain` for this case).

Comment: Moving my shared kotlin file to src/commonMain/kotlin fixed it. Thanks